# Loading a model checkpoint in lesser amount of memory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, memory-management, pytorch, out-of-memory

I had a question that I can't find any answers to online. I have trained a model whose checkpoint file is about *20 GB*. Since I do not have enough RAM with my system (or [Colaboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Colaboratory)/[Kaggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaggle) either - the limit being 16 GB), I can't use my model for predictions.

I know that the model has to be loaded into memory for the inferencing to work. However, is there a workaround or a method that can:

1. Save some memory and be able to load it in 16 GB of RAM (for CPU), or the memory in the [TPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_Processing_Unit)/[GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit)
2. Can use any framework (since I would be working with both) [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow) + [Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras), or [PyTorch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyTorch) (which I am using right now)

Is such a method even possible to do in either of these libraries? One of my tentative solutions was not load it in chunks perhaps, essentially maintaining a buffer for the model weights and biases and performing calculations accordingly - though I haven't found any implementations for that.

> I would also like to add that I wouldn't mind the performance slowdown since it is to be expected with low-specification hardware. As long as it doesn't take more than two weeks :) I can definitely wait that long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoy can try the following:

1. split model by two parts
2. load weights to the both parts separately calling `model.load_weights(by_name=True)`
3. call the first model with your input
4. call the second model with the output of the first model

Comment: I am using `FairSeq` LIbrary, so this method is a bit cumbersome since I would have to change a _lot_ of code. Is there any easier method?